# How to open multiple tabs and switch between through Selenium and Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, window-handles

I googled for this code, but not getting proper code. I have a scenario where our application having 5 modules, i want to open it on each tab because i need to switch between them multiple times plz help

this is not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample example to open multiple tabs and switch between them through Selenium Webdriver:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class WINDOW_HANDLE_ITERATE_Firefox 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          String parent_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println("Parent Window Handle is: "+driver.getWindowHandle());
          System.out.println("Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
          ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
          new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindows_1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
          System.out.println("Total Windows: "+allWindows_1.size());
          for(String hand1:allWindows_1)
          if(!parent_window.equals(hand1))
          {
              driver.switchTo().window(hand1);
              new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Facebook"));
              String first_child_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
              System.out.println("First Child Window Handle is: "+first_child_window);
              System.out.println("First Child Window Page Title is: "+driver.getTitle());
              driver.close();
          }
          driver.switchTo().window(parent_window);
          System.out.println("Current Window Handle is : "+driver.getWindowHandle()+ " which is same as "+parent_window +", which is the parent window handle" );
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  Parent Window Handle is: 6442450945
  Page Title is: Google
  Total Windows: 2
  First Child Window Handle is: 6442450949
  First Child Window Page Title is: Facebook – log in or sign up
  Current Window Handle is : 6442450945 which is same as 6442450945, which is the parent window handle
  ```

Comment: @Ashwath What does the error says? Update the question with the error stack trace. I have used `JavascriptExecutor`  to open a new tab forcibly which must be done through your application itself when you click on some of the element. Rest of the logic would remain **as it is**.

Comment: it is working now, i imported JavascriptExecutor, can u explain how can i modify this code to open another tab?

Answer (score 0):

Using getWindowHandles you can switch url multiple time.Here first i switch url and identify the tab,Everytab should a unique url and we can identify it by url.

```
   for (String window : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(window);
    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("google.com")) {    
     //Your operation     
    }       
    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("yahoo.com")) {
    }
    //Your operation
    }
```

For example you open google and yahoo in two tab then you can switch tab and identify the tab and do any operation there.

Hope it will help you

Comment: It opens blank tab

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

**To open new tab using JavascriptExecutor,**

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Will control on tab as according to index:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Driver control on main tab:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```